# Feature request: more flexible "watch" and "ignore" settings

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I watch some tags, and ignore others. Generally I don't rely on the main display to highlight things, I click on each watched tag to filter messages with that tag.

Mostly this gives me what I want, but sometimes a question has both kinds in it.  In that case the "ignore" wins, which is usually what I want, but not always.  One particular tag that I watch has low traffic, and I'd like to see it even if it also has some of the ignore tags in it.

A suggestion for how to do this is to allow more than "on" and "off" for the tags.  Maybe make it numeric:  if the total of the watches exceeds the total of the ignores, then I will see the question.

A simpler version would be just to have two levels of watching:  the first level is what we have now, where "ignore" overrides it.  The second level would always let me see the question.

Comment: What if you kept your existing watch/ignore tag settings but set up a filter for that small tag? Filters seem to show all questions meeting the criteria, even if you're ignoring a tag.

Comment: @Laurel:  thanks for the suggestion, but it's not working for me.  If my filter just shows questions tagged `rgl` but I ignore `shiny`, I don't get the most recent `rgl` question.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it works. For some reason my tags list didn't save when I was testing so I was seeing the wrong thing.